# script doesn't support inline

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using nest for elasticsearch querying. Here is my query.

```
 Client.Search<Model>(
                   a =>
                       a.Query(
                           b => b.Bool(c => c.Must(d => d.Script(e => e.Inline("doc['firstname'].value == doc['lastname'].value"))))));
```

My intention is here to get the records whose first name and last name is equal. But elasticsearch query is working in sense. Here is that query

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
       "filter": {
           "script": {
              "script": "doc['firstname'].value == doc['lastname'].value"
           }
       }
    }
    }
```

But I am getting script doesn't support inline response with nest

Comment: What version of NEST and elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: I am using 2.0.5 version of nest  <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NEST" version="2.0.5" targetFramework="net452" />

Comment: And what version of ES, 2.x?

Comment: What do you see when you run following request in your browser `http://localhost:9200`?

Comment: It works fine on http://localhost:9200 when executed using sesne. But failing with nest

Comment: what version of Elasticsearch are you running NEST 2.x against?

Answer (score 0):

[`filtered` queries are deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_filtered_literal_query_and_literal_query_literal_filter_deprecated) in Elasticsearch 2.x and the [queries and filters have merged](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_queries_and_filters_merged) into one concept called queries, which act as both queries and filters, depending on the context in which they are used (much simpler!)

You can rewrite the query that you have using NEST 2.x (*which is **only** compatible with Elasticsearch 2.x*)

```
client.Search<Model>(a => a
    .Query(b => b
        .Bool(c => c
            .Filter(d => d
                .Script(e => e
                    .Inline("doc['firstname'].value == doc['lastname'].value")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which can be shortened even further using the `+` unary operator on the query descriptor

```
client.Search<Model>(a => a
    .Query(b => +b
        .Script(e => e
            .Inline("doc['firstname'].value == doc['lastname'].value")
        )
    )
);
```

Both produce the following query json

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "inline": "doc['firstname'].value == doc['lastname'].value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[Groovy (the default)dynamic scripting is off by default since Elasticsearch 1.4.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#modules-scripting), so you will need to enable this for inline scripts.

Comment: Still no luck.. getting same error. I have enabled inline scripts in elastic config. script.inline: on
script.indexed: on

Comment: Can you add the value of `.DebugInformation` from the response to your question?

Comment: ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData) in c:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection.cs:line 138
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>

Comment: @user6171782 Could you add the above DebugInformation to your question please? Additionally, please also set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` on your `ConnectionSettings` so debug information will capture the request and response